# Split the agents equally using SelectOutput5 in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am using selectOutput5 in my model.

[image]

On the basis of the probability being equal for all the output ports, The number of agents who came out should be equal, but that is not the case.

[image]

Please let me know how I can split the agents equally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want them to be split equally you can use the "Exit Number" option and use a counter that will increment everytime, and when it reaches 3, the counter goes back to 1

so the counter starts with 1
Exit Number is equal to counter

then whenever an agent exits, you do

```
counter++;
if(counter==4) counter=1;
```

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: just experiment with exit number option and you will discover it on your own

Answer (score 2):

You should also understand *why* this happens: The conditions are computed sequentially, not at the same time.

So it first checks the first condition. Only if that is `false` will it even bother with the second, and so on.

So you'd need to have *larger* values from 1 condition to the next, which is not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using probability, I use the condition for selectOutput5.

**For example:**

If I have 3 racks, I want to split 18 agents equally among them. Then my conditions in selectoutput5 will look like this.

condition 1 : `RackStore1.size() <6`

condition 2 : `Rackstore2.size() <6`

condition 3 : `Rackstore3.size() <6`

condition 4 : `false`

The agents will split equally among the racks.